# Raw input not working as I expected - am I missing a module?

Tags: python

very basic question I'm afraid! 
I'm a Python newbie, just getting started. I've tried a few ways of getting the following to work, and now I'm wondering whether there was a module I need to import to get raw_input to work? I'm on Python 2.7.10.
I want to print "Jane is awesome" if the user input is Jane, and for all other user inputs, print name + "is not awesome". But it always prints name + "is not awesome", even when I enter Jane.

1)

```
while True:
    name = raw_input("What is your name?")
    if name == "Jane":
        print name + " is awesome"
        break
    else:
        print name + " is not awesome"
```

2)

```
endprogram = 0
while endprogram != 1:
    name = raw_input ("What is your name?")
    while name != "Jane":
        print name + " is not awesome"
        name = raw_input ("What is your name?")
    print "Jane is awesome!"
    endprogram = 1
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't enter extra spaces and used `Jane` in the exact same case? Use `print repr(name)` to have Python echo the value as a string literal, which will show any special characters as escape sequences. It'll make it crystal clear why your code isn't working.

Comment: Otherwise, your first attempt works *just fine* when you enter `Jane`.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was doing, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both pieces of code work just fine. Enter `Jane` and it'll break out:

```
>>> while True:
...     name = raw_input("What is your name?")
...     if name == "Jane":
...         print name + " is awesome"
...         break
...     else:
...         print name + " is not awesome"
...
What is your name?Martijn
Martijn is not awesome
What is your name?Jane
Jane is awesome
```

Add in a [`repr()` function call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) to help debug any issues you may have, such as additional whitespace or missing capitalisation or special characters other than ASCII:

```
>>> while True:
...     name = raw_input("What is your name?")
...     print 'You entered:', repr(name)
...     if name == "Jane":
...         print name + " is awesome"
...         break
...     else:
...         print name + " is not awesome"
...
What is your name?Martijn
You entered: 'Martijn'
Martijn is not awesome
What is your name? Jane
You entered: ' Jane'
 Jane is not awesome
What is your name?jané
You entered: 'jan\xc3\xa9'
jané is not awesome
What is your name?Jane
You entered: 'Jane'
Jane is awesome
```

Note the initial space in my first 'attempt' to enter `Jane` (the quotes around the value show there is a space there). When entering an `é`, my terminal sends UTF-8 bytes to Python, showing up as two escaped values, hex C3 and A9.

Comment: Just realised I was typing a space before the name in my user input each time. Facepalm. Sounds like this repr() function could be really useful, thank you!!